# CNN AE shape missmatch

Tags: python, filter, conv-neural-network, shapes

Im working on MNIST data set .
im tyring to build a CNN AE that trains for the different number of filters.  then reprt test and train loss and plots them

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Define hyperparameters
batch_size = 128
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 15
latent_dim = 10,
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") # Define the device
# Define transforms to normalize the data
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()])


# Load the MNIST dataset
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transform, download=True)
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=transform, download=True)

# Define data loaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, num_filters):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, num_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, 2*num_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(2*num_filters, 4*num_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(4*num_filters*7*7, latent_dim)
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 4*self.num_filters*7*7)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, num_filters):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 4*num_filters*7*7)
        self.conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(4*num_filters, 2*num_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(2*num_filters, num_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(num_filters, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 4*self.num_filters, 7, 7)
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.conv3(x))
        return x
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim, num_filters):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(latent_dim, num_filters)
        self.decoder = Decoder(latent_dim, num_filters)
        self.num_filters = num_filters
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filter_list_my=[3,4,5,7]
def train_model_for_filters(filter_list):
    train_losses = []
    test_losses = []
    final_train_losses = []
    latent_dim=25
    for num_filters in filter_list:
        print("Training model with {} filters...".format(num_filters))
        # Define the model, loss function, and optimizer
        model = Autoencoder(latent_dim, num_filters).to(device)
        criterion = nn.BCELoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

        # Train the model
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            running_loss = 0.0
            for data in train_loader:
                img, _ = data
                img = img.to(device)

                # forward pass
                output = model(img)
                loss = criterion(output, img)

                # backward pass and optimize
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                running_loss += loss.item()

            train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
            train_losses.append(train_loss)

            # Print the training loss for every epoch
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Train Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, train_loss))
            running_loss = 0.0
        
        # Test the model and calculate test loss
        with torch.no_grad():
            test_loss = 0.0
            for data in test_loader:
                img, _ = data
                img = img.to(device)

                output = model(img)
                loss = criterion(output, img)
                test_loss += loss.item()

            test_loss /= len(test_loader)
            test_losses.append(test_loss)

            # Print the test loss and the filter used for the last epoch
            print('Test Loss: {:.4f}, Filter Used: {}'.format(test_loss, num_filters))
            final_train_losses.append(train_losses[-1])
    # Plot the train and test losses as a function of filters
    plt.plot(filter_list, final_train_losses, label='Train Loss')
    plt.plot(filter_list, test_losses, label='Test Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Number of Filters')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Training and Test Loss for Different Numbers of Filters')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

train_model_for_filters(filter_list_my)
```

Unfortunately i keep getting this error :

T

```
raining model with 3 filters...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-73b97a54d860> in <cell line: 66>()
     64     plt.show()
     65 
---> 66 train_model_for_filters(filter_list_my)

4 frames
<ipython-input-65-875239e759b9> in forward(self, x)
     12         x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
     13         x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
---> 14         x = x.view(x.size(0), 4*self.num_filters*7*7)
     15         x = self.fc(x)
     16         return x

RuntimeError: shape '[128, 588]' is invalid for input of size 1204224
```

I have edit my CNN multiple times and cant seem to understand what is wrong . would be happy for your help :)